# Tableau Reader Limitation in Data storage

Tags: tableau-api

I am working with tableau reader . want to know tableau reader limitations. i got features [Here](http://www.tableausoftware.com/products/reader?signin=858ea3ad5e6336a203a8b8c29104cae3) but i want to check limitation.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitations of Tableau Reader are as follows:

1. Tableau Reader can only open packaged workbooks that contain live, file-based live connections (since these files are included in the packaged workbook), or extracted data
2. Visualisations can be interacted with (filter, drill-down and sort) but not modified

Comment: Thank you @Talvalin. What about maximum size of .twbx file. i mean the capacity to store maximum data in that file.

Comment: Theoretically, there is no limitation, but I imagine that there may be an issue with sharing a .twbx that contained an extract file that was hundreds of MBs in size, simply because transferring it around would be a pain.